# запись возвращаемого значения функции с вопросом в конце

Tags: c#

хм, запись возвращаемого значения функции с вопросом подразумевает возврат неопределённого типа? что-то не могу найти ссылку на такое...

```
public Vector3? GetTargetPosition()
{
    if (particles.Keys.Count == 0)
        return null;
    return target;
}
```

убираю вопрос - ругается на null... )

Comment: ищите на `Nullable`

Comment: да. В C# и Visual Basic, пометить как допускающие значение NULL тип значения с помощью ? нотации после тип значения. Например int? в C# или Integer? в Visual Basic объявляет тип целочисленного значения, которое может быть назначено null.

Comment: Ну вот то же самое и `Vector3?`.

Answer (score 3):

Как указано в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/)

> Типы, допускающие значения NULL, имеют следующие характеристики.
>
> 1. Типы, допускающие значение NULL, представляют переменные типа значения, которым может быть назначено значение `null`. Нельзя создать тип, допускающий значение NULL, на основе ссылочного типа. (Ссылочные типы всегда поддерживают значение `null`.)
> 2. Синтаксис T? является сокращением для `Nullable<T>`, где T является типом значения. Эти две формы записи являются взаимозаменяемыми.

---

Для того, чтобы функция могла вернуть `null` в качестве возвращаемого значения нужно указать тип, допускающий значения NULL. Так как `Vector3` является структурой (тип-значение), нужно использовать `Nullable<Vector3>` или сокращенную форму `Vector3?`.