# Object to nullable object

Tags: c#, .net

Есть поле, которое используется в свойстве. Появилась необходимость переделать Product Product в Nullable Product. Но не могу никак привести к нему не nullable поле _product. 
Есть ли быстрые и красивые способы это сделать, без дополнительных классов, Activator.CreateInstance, и т.д?

```
private Product _product;

public Product? Product //The type 'Product' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable<T>'
{
    get
    {
        if (_productId == 0) return null;
        if (_product == null)
        {
            //если _product тоже поменять тип, то будет ругаться здесь.
            _product = ProductsCollection.Instance[_productId];
        }
        return _product; // Cannot implicitly convert type 'namespace.Product' to 'namespace.Product?'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
        return (Product?)_product; //The type 'Product' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable<T>'
    }
}
```

Comment: если `Product` - это класс, то ему не нужен `?` он и так `nullable`, То есть может принимать значение `null`

Comment: @Grundy ответом?

Comment: @andreycha, это скорее догадка. Мне кажется у нас что-то было похожее. Что-то вроде [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/746163/186999) Но там немного другое

Comment: @Grundy текст ошибки однозначно указывает, что `Product` у автора -- это уже nullable тип.

Comment: @Grundy,  но у меня не получается использовать это свойство в виде Product?.Price. Раз оно nullable, то почему не даёт?

Comment: @andreycha, добавил, но похоже у автора немного другая проблема в итоге :)

Comment: @ai-zer если у вас не работает `Product?.Price` - то и спрашивайте про `Product?.Price`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

если `Product` - это класс, то ему **не нужен `?`** он и так *nullable*, то есть может принимать значение *null*.

То есть первоначальный код вполне сработает:

```
private Product _product;

public Product Product //The type 'Product' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable<T>'
{
    get
    {
        if (_productId == 0) return null;
        if (_product == null)
        {
            _product = ProductsCollection.Instance[_productId];
        }
        return _product; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Простите, не до конца разобрался. Да, так работает var c = Product?.Price ?? 0; но при использовании в лямбда не хочет   Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductViewModel>()
.ForMember(o => o.FullPrice, o => o.MapFrom(m => m.IsProduct() ? m.Product?.Price() ?? 0 : m.SecondProduct?.Price() ? 0)) //An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator.

Comment: @ai-zer, Тут по сути совсем другая ошибка: _An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator._ - то есть в этом маппере запрещено использовать `?.`  в переданных выражениях